# Picasso New Version 2.5.2: Not Working with Transformation

Tags: android, android-image, picasso, illegalargumentexception

Hello Picasso+Android Users,

I have used following version of **Picasso** and its working with following **Transformation** snippet:

> compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'

and created following **Transformation** for `Image Transformation`:

```
public class ImageTransformation implements Transformation {

    int maxWidth;
    int maxHeight;

    public ImageTransformation(ImageView imageView) {
        this.maxWidth = imageView.getWidth();
        this.maxHeight = imageView.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int targetWidth, targetHeight;
        double aspectRatio;

        if (source.getWidth() > source.getHeight()) {
            targetWidth = maxWidth;
            aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
            targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);
        } else {
            targetHeight = maxHeight;
            aspectRatio = (double) source.getWidth() / (double) source.getHeight();
            targetWidth = (int) (targetHeight * aspectRatio);
        }

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
        if (result != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return maxWidth + "x" + maxHeight;
    }
}
```

and Used like:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(photo.getLink())
                .error(R.drawable.ic_place_holder_circle)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_place_holder_circle)
                .transform(new ImageTransformation(holder.albumPhotoDetailSubMainImage))
                .into(holder.albumPhotoDetailSubMainImage);
```

Now i want to use `.priority()` which is available in new following version:

> compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

But it is giving me error of **Transformation** like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:815)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:794)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:725)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.transformResult(BitmapHunter.java:558)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:232)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
```

I am getting this error in new version of [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso/) only.

Is there any solution to solve?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: check `holder.albumPhotoDetailSubMainImage == null` or not

Comment: @MD Its working fine with old library.

Comment: The `ImageView` is likely not built yet which is why height/width is 0 (from your stacktrace). I would suggest using `picasso.resize(width, height)` instead of your transformation.

Comment: @JaredRummler Thanks for your suggestion but i want to do it dynamically as per size of `ImageView` thats why i have used `Transformation`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the following instead:

```
        public ImageTransformation(ImageView imageView) {
            this.maxWidth = imageView.getLayoutParams().width; //imageView.getWidth();
            this.maxHeight = imageView.getLayoutParams().height; //imageView.getHeight();
            // check
            if (this.maxWidth <= 0) {
                this.maxWidth = ...
            }
            if (this.maxHeight <= 0) {
                this.maxHeight = ...
            }
        }
```

About the exception, actually, ver 2.3.2 also got it, however, it has different way to process the exception. You can see 2 following screenshots:

Ver 2.3.2:

[image: Ver 2.3.2]

Ver 2.5.2:

[image: Ver 2.5.2]